# Verilog Code Optimisation

Tags: fpga, verilog, programmable-logic, hdl

I have recently become involved in FPGA design and I am just testing out some new Zync SoC hardware. I have followed a tutorial online to blink some LED's however I have modified it to blink all the LED's at different rates. My code is as follows and describes a potential 8 element LED counter:

```
//  Simple LED logic
// reg [28-1:0] led_reg2 [8-1:0]; // 28 bit wide, 8 element memory  
reg [28-1:0] led_cnt_0; // 29 bit LED counter 
reg [27-1:0] led_cnt_1;
...

always @(posedge sys_clk_i) begin // on every positive edge of system clock 
    if (!sys_rstn_i) begin // if the system is reset 
        // led_reg2{8-1:0} <= 28'h0; // failed attempt to describe resetting an 8 bit bank of registers to 0
        led_cnt_0 <= 28'h0; // reset the LED counter 
        led_cnt_1 <= 27'h0; 
        ...
    end 
    else begin 
        led_cnt_0 <= led_cnt_0 + 28'h1; // increment counter 
        led_cnt_1 <= led_cnt_1 + 27'h1;
        ...
    end 
end

assign led_o = {led_cnt_0[28-1],led_cnt_1[27-1],led_cnt_2[26-1],led_cnt_3[25-1],led_cnt_4[24-1],led_cnt_5[23-1],led_cnt_6[22-1],led_cnt_7[21-1]};
```

My code does as desired and they blink at rates equal to 125e6 / 2^n 
- However, I am not satisfied with the layout of my code and the syntax, considering Verilog is designed to solve such problems of this nature.

**My question is:**

What is the correct/suitable syntax of such a problem? 
I have made attempts to solve this by making a 28 bit wide, 8 element register, however I don't know how to correctly control it. I have spent quite a while looking for similar problems and syntax's but have been unable to implement it correctly. I also think a trial and error approach to this is not the way forward, as this is not simply programming.

Additionally could anybody recommend suitable reading material to learn and practise Verilog, I am familiar with the structures etc, through lecturers a few years ago but have no clue with regards to the implementation.

Many thanks.

Comment: You realise that `led_cnt_1[26]` and `led_cnt_0[26]` will be identical right? Same for `led_cnt_2[25]` and `led_cnt_1[25]` and `led_cnt_0[25]`. And so on and so forth.

Comment: So why not simply: `assign led_o = led_cnt_0[27:20]`?

Comment: (This is my first practical investigation into something on an FPGA) 
Thinking about this further it would be better to create a a single 29 bit counter and tap off the lines of the flip flops onto the different LED lines. This way you could get different blinking rates, however how would you reset the state of the LED, could you introduce a buffer flip flop ?

Comment: In your attempt to describe resetting led_reg2, you can use SystemVerilog syntax, `led_reg2 = '{default:'0};` simply. But it depends on what FPGA synthesizer you use.